# ¿Por qué este uso de jQuery es ineficiente?

Tags: jquery

Necesito marcar como seleccionada una opción de un  `select`. Para hacerlo uso jQuery con la siguiente sentencia:

`$("#idSelect option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");`

Pero mi `IDE` (PhpStorm) me avisa con lo siguiente

> Uso de jQuery ineficiente

Sin embargo, cuando uso esta sentencia:

`$("#idSelect").find("option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");`

No me genera ningún aviso.
Ambas sentencias funcionan correctamente y no generan ningún aviso en el depurador del navegador.

La pregunta es ¿hay alguna diferencia de rendimiento entre estas dos sentencias?¿o es algo que PhpStorm interpreta así por su cuenta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpStorm no lo está interpretando así por su cuenta, realmente la segunda opción es algo más rápida (o podría serlo). Puedes encontrar una explicación en la [documentación de jQuery sobre cómo optimizar los selectores](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/) (en inglés).

Esto se debe a que cuando haces:

```
$("#idSelect option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");
```

jQuery internamente está usando `document.querySelectorAll` (porque hay múltiples elementos en el selector), mientras que si haces:

```
$("#idSelect").find("option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Se va a usar `document.getElementById` que es más rápido (aunque esa rapidez luego se puede ver disminuida por el uso de `.find()` justo después).

Answer (score 3):

De hecho si existe una diferencia muy notoria en cuanto a rendimiento.

```
$("#idSelect").find("option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Puede llegar a ser 2 veces más rápida que:

```
$("#idSelect option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Gracias a [Scott Kosman](https://twitter.com/humantorch) por acá tienes su [referencia](https://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/).